# I developed an eclipse editor using ecllipse-rcp concepts .My requirement is to build the project using maven

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I developed an eclipse editor using eclipse-rcp concepts .My requirement is to build the project using maven.
So i wrote the pom with packaging type=bundle using apache felix concepts.
After building the project, the project jar has the class files,plugin.xml and the manifest file.

Now, I am dropping this jar in plugins folder of eclipse.I want to open files of a certain extension with this editor. But my eclipseis not showing my editor name in the Internal/External editor list, even though the plugin is the plugins folder of eclipse.

Please help.

Comment: Dropping a plugin in the plugins directory has not been a supported way of installing a plugin for a long time. You must create an installable plugin and install it with Install New Software. You might get the plugin to work by starting Eclipse with the -clean option.

Comment: The requirement is as such that it should be dropped into the plugins folder and used.What changes should be done for starting eclipse with -clean?

Comment: Well the requirement is wrong. This is not supported. A proper install is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build Eclipse plug-ins with Maven, you should use Tycho: https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/. It provides specific packaging types for handling Eclipse plugins and features (groups of plugins).